# How do I make a batch file terminate upon encountering an error?

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file that's calling the same executable over and over with different parameters.  How do I make it terminate immediately if one of the calls returns an error code of any level?

Basically, I want the equivalent of MSBuild's `ContinueOnError=false`.

Answer (score 372, accepted):

Check the `errorlevel` in an `if` statement, and then `exit /b` (exit the **b**atch file only, not the entire cmd.exe process) for values other than 0.

```
same-executable-over-and-over.exe /with different "parameters"
if %errorlevel% neq 0 exit /b %errorlevel%
```

If you want the value of the errorlevel to propagate outside of your batch file

```
if %errorlevel% neq 0 exit /b %errorlevel%
```

but if this is inside a `for` it gets a bit tricky. You'll need something more like:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%f in (C:\Windows\*) do (
    same-executable-over-and-over.exe /with different "parameters"
    if !errorlevel! neq 0 exit /b !errorlevel!
)
```

**Edit:** You have to check the error after each command. There's no global "on error goto" type of construct in cmd.exe/command.com batch. I've also updated my code per [CodeMonkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/734598#734744), although I've never encountered a negative errorlevel in any of my batch-hacking on XP or Vista.

Comment: Is there a way to state it once for the entire file?  "On error goto" or something similar?

Comment: +1 for the negative errorlevel check. Had a script silently fail because of a negative result.

Comment: Careful: the enabledelayedexpansion is CRITICAL and also required for an if/else or any other block

Comment: @system-PAUSE is there any difference between the first two 'if' shown?

Comment: Delayed expansion enabled/disabled or command extensions (required for `neq`) enabled/disabled does not matter on using `if not errorlevel 1 exit /B` as explained by Microsoft in support article [Using command redirection operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) and in help output on running `if /?` in a cmd window. The current errorlevel (exit code) is kept on exiting processing of batch file with `exit /B`. Note: `exit` with parameter `/B` requires enabled command extensions, see [Where does GOTO :EOF return to?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37515901/)

Comment: Any idea how to get this to a single line? I tried using & to chain commands but the %errorlevel% doesn't contain what I'm looking for till after execution is done.

Comment: I don't really know how to interpret this answer. Does it mean that I just add the line `if %errorlevel% neq 0 exit /b %errorlevel%` at the end of the batch file?

Comment: @BradLaney, here is an alt. explanation. When the command line processes your lines it replaces all the %variables% with their values BEFORE the line is processed. So when you do something like: `ICauseProblems.bat && if %errorlevel% NEQ 0 echo Failed...` the %errorlevel% is filled in with whatever value it was BEFORE the 'ICauseProblems.bat' has even ran. When you turn on delayed expansion you can now ALSO do !variable! instead, and they're processing is delayed until their actual use.

Comment: @FabianRöling [cont. ^--] So, you both need to use 'setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion' and then use !ErrorLevel! or whatever variable you want instead of %ErrorLevel%. If you are ever in a one-off situation you can do "cmd /v:on" to enable it outside of batch files. In fact, I modified my command prompt shortcut to be "cmd.exe /v:on & echo Delayed Expansion: Enabled" so it's always on. Just don't assume anyone else has this because it's probably so uncommon it's effectively just me =(. But.. if you wanna be a cool guy who almost ends his post in a sad face like me go ahead! =̶)̶  =(. Nice.

Comment: I lied and now I can't edit what I said =/ To make that cmd.exe launch like I said you need to do: `cmd.exe /v:on /k "echo Delayed Expansion: Enabled... & echo.` Whatever you do just don't do what I ACTUALLY found out I did which is: My cmd.exe launches as this monstrocity: `cmd.exe /v:on /k "set "[unlikely]=1" & (echo. | set /p=Delayed Expansion: ) & if "![unlikely]!"=="1" (echo Enabled^!) else (echo Disabled... =/)`. I mean, it works... That's something.

Comment: Take note that for some commands (e.g. Robocopy) there are some exitcode > 0 that is not really an error https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy-exit.html

Answer (score 295):

Add `|| goto :label` to each line, and then define a `:label`.

For example, create this .cmd file:

```dos
@echo off

echo Starting very complicated batch file...
ping -invalid-arg || goto :error
echo OH noes, this shouldn't have succeeded.
goto :EOF

:error
echo Failed with error #%errorlevel%.
exit /b %errorlevel%
```

See also [question about exiting batch file subroutine](https://superuser.com/questions/80485/exit-batch-file-from-subroutine).

Comment: It's a very common idiom in most shell scripting languages, and it reads well: "Do this, or this if it fails.."

Comment: I use a SET to keep manually track of the line number: `command || (SET ErrorLine=102 && goto :error)`

Comment: @MarcelValdezOrozco Seems to me that this is what `||` was created for in the first place. Maybe not goto in particular, but "try, do this on error" as Fowl mentioned. My question is does this work for all non-zero exit codes? Positives only?

Comment: @jpmc26 yes it does, prove it it to yourself - `cmd /k exit -1 && echo success || echo fail` - prints fail.

Comment: You can even avoid the labels with something like `command || exit /b %errorlevel%`

Comment: this is also commonly used in [Debian packages](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/325705/44425)

Answer (score 131):

The shortest:

```
command || exit /b
```

If you need, you can set the exit code:

```
command || exit /b 666
```

And you can also log:

```
command || echo ERROR && exit /b
```

Comment: does exit /b by chance return the original failing exit code?

Comment: @FrankSchwieterman, yes, `%ERRORLEVEL%` is untouched when you call `exit /b`, so the error code is forwarded

Answer (score 40):

Here is a [polyglot program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyglot_(computing)) for BASH and Windows CMD that runs a series of commands and quits out if any of them fail:

```
#!/bin/bash 2> nul

:; set -o errexit
:; function goto() { return $?; }

command 1 || goto :error

command 2 || goto :error

command 3 || goto :error

:; exit 0
exit /b 0

:error
exit /b %errorlevel%
```

I have used this type of thing in the past for a multiple platform [continuous integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) script.

Answer (score 24):

One minor update, you should change the checks for "if errorlevel 1" to the following...

```
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0
```

This is because on XP you can get negative numbers as errors. 0 = no problems, anything else is a problem.

And keep in mind the way that DOS handles the "IF ERRORLEVEL" tests.  It will return true if the number you are checking for is that number or higher so if you are looking for specific error numbers you need to start with 255 and work down.

Comment: None of the Windows standard internal and external commands exit ever with a negative value. Microsoft warns any program writer to exit with a negative value, for example on MSDN article about [Environment.ExitCode Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.exitcode.aspx). In fact it must be always find out which exit code is used by an application on success and which ones on the various errors, see [HTML Help Workshop returns error after successfully compiled .chm file](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39040033/3074564) for a negative MS example on user expectations.

Answer (score 19):

I prefer the OR form of command, as I find them the most readable (as
opposed to having an if after each command). However, the naive way of
doing this, `command || exit /b %ERRORLEVEL%` is *wrong*.

This is because batch expands variables when a line is first read, rather
than when they are being used. This means that if the `command` in the line
above fails, the batch file exits properly, but it exits with return code 0,
because that is what the value of `%ERRORLEVEL%` was at the start of the
line. Obviously, this is undesirable in our script, so we have to enable
[delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html), like so:

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

command-1 || exit /b !ERRORLEVEL!
command-2 || exit /b !ERRORLEVEL!
command-3 || exit /b !ERRORLEVEL!
command-4 || exit /b !ERRORLEVEL!
```

This snippet will execute commands 1-4, and if any of them fails, it will
exit with the same exit code as the failing command did.

Comment: Your code is correct, but I believe unnecessarily verbose for simple tasks: `exit /b` with no argument will preserve the errorlevel. Your example could be simplified to `command-1 || exit /b` -- shorter and no longer requires EnableDelayedExpansion. However, your code does demonstrate valid use of EnableDelayedExpansion, which someone might build upon, for example:  `command-1 || (echo Error=!errorlevel! && exit /b)`.

Comment: @MikeClark, I don't think that's correct. I just tested it and only using delayed expansion and error level failed the batch correctly.

Comment: @MikeClark Since you do a echo command before the exit command, I expect errorlevel will be reset by the echo command, i.e. always zero

Answer (score 2):

We cannot always depend on ERRORLEVEL, because many times external programs or batch scripts do not return exit codes.

In that case we can use generic checks for failures like this:

```
IF EXIST %outfile% (DEL /F %outfile%)
CALL some_script.bat -o %outfile%
IF NOT EXIST %outfile%  (ECHO ERROR & EXIT /b)
```

And if the program outputs something to console, we can check it also.

```
some_program.exe 2>&1 | FIND "error message here" && (ECHO ERROR & EXIT /b)
some_program.exe 2>&1 | FIND "Done processing." || (ECHO ERROR & EXIT /b)
```

Answer (score 1):

No matter how I tried, the errorlevel always stays 0 even when msbuild failed. So I built my workaround:

Build Project and save log to Build.log

```
SET Build_Opt=/flp:summary;logfile=Build.log;append=true

msbuild "myproj.csproj" /t:rebuild /p:Configuration=release /fl %Build_Opt%
```

search for "0 Error" string in build log, set the result to var

```
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`find /c /i "0 Error" Build.log`) DO (
    SET var=%%F
)
echo %var%
```

get the last character, which indicates how many lines contains the search string

```
set result=%var:~-1%

echo "%result%"
```

if string not found, then error > 0, build failed

```
if "%result%"=="0" ( echo "build failed" )
```

That solution was inspired by Mechaflash's post at [How to set commands output as a variable in a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359820/how-to-set-commands-output-as-a-variable-in-a-batch-file)

and https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html

Comment: works only for counts lss than ten. Better; `for /f %%F in ('type build.log^|find /c /i "0 Error") do set result=%%F`. Note: `find "0 Error"` will also find `10 Errors`.

Answer (score -3):

```
@echo off

set startbuild=%TIME%

C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\msbuild.exe c:\link.xml /flp1:logfile=c:\link\errors.log;errorsonly /flp2:logfile=c:\link\warnings.log;warningsonly || goto :error

copy c:\app_offline.htm "\\lawpccnweb01\d$\websites\OperationsLinkWeb\app_offline.htm"

del \\lawpccnweb01\d$\websites\OperationsLinkWeb\bin\ /Q

echo Start Copy: %TIME%

set copystart=%TIME%

xcopy C:\link\_PublishedWebsites\OperationsLink \\lawpccnweb01\d$\websites\OperationsLinkWeb\ /s /y /d

del \\lawpccnweb01\d$\websites\OperationsLinkWeb\app_offline.htm

echo Started Build: %startbuild%
echo Started Copy: %copystart%
echo Finished Copy: %TIME%

c:\link\warnings.log

:error

c:\link\errors.log
```

Comment: Please add more information to your answer. Just a block of code is not very helpful.

Comment: Besides not having added any comments, your snippet doesn't look like a good candidate for explaining a functionality: it seems to contain a lot of things that are completely irrelevant to the question.