# How to set commands output as a variable in a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

Is it possible to set a statement's output of a batch file to a variable, for example:

```
findstr testing > %VARIABLE%

echo %VARIABLE%
```

Comment: Actually the original seems to be [How do I get the result of a command in a variable in windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/108439/12892).

Comment: None of the answers seems to work for me. My command is "openssl dgst -sha384 -binary %1% | openssl base64 -A" and I wish the string output to be stored in a variable in a batch/command file.

Comment: Somewhat inefficient solution: @echo off
openssl dgst -sha384 -binary %1% | openssl base64 -A > tmp
set /p a= < tmp
del tmp
echo %a%

Comment: Write a python script that does the job?

Answer (score 401):

```
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`command`) DO (
SET var=%%F
)
ECHO %var%
```

I always use the USEBACKQ so that if you have a string to insert or a long file name, you can use your double quotes without screwing up the command.

Now if your output will contain multiple lines, you can do this

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET count=1
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`command`) DO (
  SET var!count!=%%F
  SET /a count=!count!+1
)
ECHO %var1%
ECHO %var2%
ECHO %var3%
ENDLOCAL
```

Comment: Worked for me in Win7 system, thanks! (and yes, it's 7 years of usefullness)
P.S. Don't forget to expand % to %% in commands!

Comment: This works great... unless the output contains exclamation points (!), as these will be interpreted as control characters when using `ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION`

Comment: It does work well, except if you need to use `|` in which case it doesn't work.

Comment: @MattVukomanovic it works for me using `^|` in place of `|`, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/108511/5170004)

Comment: Is it possible to capture the exit code of `command` anyhow, please? I'm sure it's returning a non-zero code but `%ERRORLEVEL%` always contains 0, no matter where I try to use it (even inside the `do` block). So I guess some part of that `for` construct is overwriting it. BTW It's unbelievable how crazy looking code is needed for something so elementary.

Comment: If the command is simple (without space), you can do `set var=%command%`

Comment: backticks or simplequotes ?

Comment: @DawidFerenczyRogožan i know this is 2 years too late but just coming back to the platform  LOL. I believe you'd have to capture the %ERRORLEVEL% in the first line of the do-loop and then export the output (to a file or variable).

Comment: This bit is REALLY clever: `SET var!count!=%%F` I've not seen dynamic variable names in a batch file before.

Comment: @DavidFerenczyRogožan: Yes, you can. See example I've posted; it voids the need for a  `for` loop to capture value of a command and store in a variable.

Comment: @DavidFerenczyRogožan Have you tried `!ERRORLEVEL!` within the loop?

Comment: Note that double percent is for scripts and single percent is for command line. I got surprised by this.

Comment: Trying to use this to capture the output of an `ffprobe` command and it breaks...

Comment: @AutoBaker: no, it does not brake, and when it does, please create a new question with your problem. (do not forget to add a link to this answer)

Answer (score 126):

In a single line:

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%g IN ('your command') do (SET VAR=%%g)
```

The command output will be set in %g then in VAR.

More information here: https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html

Comment: My batch did not run with "%g". It ran with "%%g".

Comment: +Santiago Villafuerte: yes, if you're running from a batch file, but if you want to run it from the command line yourself (for example: to test it before putting it in the batch file) then you use a single %.

Comment: I have found the *your command* a bit confusing. Didn't know whether * is actually necessary (NO). Nonetheless very helpful command.

Comment: I'm getting %%g was unexpected at this time.

Comment: Use %g when on command line and %%g when i .bat file.

Answer (score 105):

I found [this thread](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/230090-45-windows-batch-file-output-program-variable) on that there Interweb thing. Boils down to:

```
@echo off 
setlocal enableextensions 
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ( 
'VER' 
) do ( 
set myvar=%%a 
) 
echo/%%myvar%%=%myvar% 
pause 
endlocal
```

You can also redirect the output of a command to a temporary file, and then put the contents of that temporary file into your variable, likesuchashereby. It doesn't work with multiline input though.

```
cmd > tmpFile 
set /p myvar= < tmpFile 
del tmpFile
```

Credit to the thread on Tom's Hardware.

Comment: Only drawback to bottom approach (which is preferable in all other ways) is that it doesn't work with multi-line output.

Comment: For VER I would go another way:
for /f "tokens=2 delims=[,]" %%a in ('ver') do set version %%a
echo %version%

Comment: you are the second result for likesuchashereby -  https://imagebin.ca/v/4NPSlQFgifce

Comment: Your second example helped me greatly in writing a batch file to check the version of chromedriver.exe versus a text file containing a version number.  I'm an old DOS dinosaur, and was not aware of the switches to the set command.  The other stuff was overkill for me.

Answer (score 40):

If you don't want to output to a temp file and then read into a variable, this code stores result of command direct into a variable:

```
FOR /F %i IN ('findstr testing') DO set VARIABLE=%i
echo %VARIABLE%
```

If you want to enclose search string in double quotes:

```
FOR /F %i IN ('findstr "testing"') DO set VARIABLE=%i
```

If you want to store this code in a batch file, add an extra % symbol:

```
FOR /F %%i IN ('findstr "testing"') DO set VARIABLE=%%i
```

A useful example to count the number of files in a directory & store in a variable:
(illustrates piping)

```
FOR /F %i IN ('dir /b /a-d "%cd%" ^| find /v /c "?"') DO set /a count=%i
```

Note the use of single quotes instead of double quotes " or grave accent ` in the command brackets. This is cleaner alternative to `delims`, `tokens` or `usebackq` in `for` loop.

**Update 27/8/2021:**

Another method is to set errorlevel variable, although many would discourage [setting errorlevel](http://batcheero.blogspot.com/2007/07/never-set-errorlevel.html) on large scripts or when new to cmd flavor of the installed OS variant.

This method works where (return) value to be stored fits in a 32-bit integer.

eg.
to count the number of files in a directory & store in a variable called `count`:

```
(dir /b /a-d ^| find /v /c "?") | (set /p myVar=& cmd /c exit /b %myVar%)
set count=%errorlevel%
```

Verbose - Win CMD integer limits tests:

> Win CMD arithmetic limit: 2147483647 (32-bit integers)
> Stack overflow would continue count at -2147483648
> and reset again after reaching 2147483647

```
REM See tests below:
cmd /c exit /b 2147483647
echo %errorlevel%
2147483647

cmd /c exit /b 2147483648
echo %errorlevel%
-2147483648

cmd /c exit /b 2147483649
echo %errorlevel%
-2147483647
```

Above method can be modified to return encoded strings to be decoded in parent process (within 32 bit limitation).

A 3rd illustration, although of limited use (because the variable is set in child process, not parent) is:

```
(dir /b /a-d ^| find /v /c "?") | (set /p myVar=& set myVar)
```

In this case the value of myVar is set to the number of files in the directory

Tested on Win 10 CMD.

Comment: this didn't work for me

Comment: What's your Windows version &  build?

Comment: Windows 10 64bits

Comment: I've tested on Win 10 x64. Which code didn't work for you?

Answer (score 32):

To read a file...

```
set /P Variable=<File.txt
```

To Write a file

```
@echo %DataToWrite%>File.txt
```

note; having spaces before the <> character causes a space to be added at the end of the variable, also

To add to a file,like a logger program,
First make a file with a single enter key in it called e.txt

```
set /P Data=<log0.log
set /P Ekey=<e.txt
@echo %Data%%Ekey%%NewData%>log0.txt
```

your log will look like this

```
Entry1
Entry2
```

and so on

Anyways a couple useful things

Comment: Thank you for your answer. BTW "set /P Variable=<File.txt" reads only first line of file

Comment: your_command | set /P VAR=

Answer (score 28):

These answers were all so close to the answer that I needed.  This is an attempt to expand on them.

### In a Batch file

If you're running from within a `.bat` file and you want a single line that allows you to export a complicated command like `jq -r ".Credentials.AccessKeyId" c:\temp\mfa-getCreds.json` to a variable named `AWS_ACCESS_KEY` then you want this:

```
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%g IN (`jq -r ".Credentials.AccessKeyId" c:\temp\mfa-getCreds.json`) do (SET "AWS_ACCESS_KEY=%%g")
```

### On the Command Line

If you're at the `C:\` prompt you want a single line that allows you to run a complicated command like `jq -r ".Credentials.AccessKeyId" c:\temp\mfa-getCreds.json` to a variable named `AWS_ACCESS_KEY` then you want this:

```
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %g IN (`jq -r ".Credentials.AccessKeyId" c:\temp\mfa-getCreds.json`) do (SET "AWS_ACCESS_KEY=%g")
```

### Explanation

The only difference between the two answers above is that on the command line, you use a single % in your variable.  In a batch file, you have to double up on the percentage signs (%%).

Since the command includes colons, quotes, and parentheses, you need to include the `USEBACKQ` line in the options so that you can use backquotes to specify the command to run and then all kinds of funny characters inside of it.

Comment: Well, apparently someone is having the exact same problem I'm facing of the wonders of piping JSON from the AWS cli using batch scripts hah

Answer (score 19):

Some notes and some tricks.

The 'official' way to assign result to a variable is with [**`FOR /F`**](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) though in the other answers is shown how a temporary file can be used also.

For command processing [**`FOR`**](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) command has two forms depending if the `usebackq` option is used. In the all examples below the whole output is used without splitting it.

```
FOR /f "tokens=* delims=" %%A in ('whoami') do @set "I-Am=%%A"
FOR /f "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%A in (`whoami`) do @set "I-Am=%%A"
```

and if used directly in the console:

```
FOR /f "tokens=* delims=" %A in ('whoami') do set "I-Am=%A"
FOR /f "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %A in (`whoami`) do set "I-Am=%A"
```

`%%A` is a temporary variable available only on the `FOR` command context and is called token.The two forms can be useful in case when you are dealing with arguments containing specific quotes. It is especially useful with REPL interfaces of other languages or WMIC.
Though in both cases the expression can be put in double quotes and it still be processed.

Here's an example with python (it is possible to transition the expression in the brackets on a separate line which is used for easier reading):

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in (
  '"python -c ""print("""Message from python""")"""'
) do (
    echo processed message from python: "%%a"
)
```

To use an assigned variable in the same **FOR** block check also the [**DELAYED EXPANSION**](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

### And some tricks

To save yourself from writing all the arguments for the FOR command you can use ***[MACRO](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-macros.html)*** for assigning the result to variable:

```
@echo off

::::: ---- defining the assign macro ---- ::::::::
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
(set LF=^
%=EMPTY=%
)
set ^"\n=^^^%LF%%LF%^%LF%%LF%^^"

::set argv=Empty
set assign=for /L %%n in (1 1 2) do ( %\n%
   if %%n==2 (%\n%
      setlocal enableDelayedExpansion%\n%
      for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%A in ("!argv!") do (%\n%
         for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%# in ('%%~A') do endlocal^&set "%%~B=%%#" %\n%
      ) %\n%
   ) %\n%
) ^& set argv=,

::::: -------- ::::::::


:::EXAMPLE
%assign% "WHOAMI /LOGONID",result
echo %result%
```

the first argument to the macro is the command and the second the name of the variable we want to use and both are separated by `,` (comma). Though this is suitable only for straight forward scenarios.

If we want a similar macro for the console we can use ***[DOSKEY](https://ss64.com/nt/doskey.html)***

```
doskey assign=for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=," %a in ("$*") do @for /f "tokens=* delims=" %# in ('"%a"') do @set "%b=%#"
rem  -- example --
assign WHOAMI /LOGONID,my-id
echo %my-id%
```

DOSKEY does accept double quotes as enclosion for arguments so this also is useful for more simple scenarios.

FOR also works well with [**pipes**](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) which can be used for chaining commands (though it is not so good for assigning a variable.

```
hostname |for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%# in ('more') do @(ping %%#)
```

Which also can be beautified with macros:

```
@echo off
:: --- defining chain command macros ---
set "result-as-[arg]:=|for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%# in ('more') do @("
set "[arg]= %%#)"
:::  --------------------------  :::

::Example:
hostname %result-as-[arg]:% ping %[arg]%
```

And for completnes macros for the temp file approach (no doskey definition ,but it also can be easy done.If you have a SSD this wont be so slow):

```
@echo off

:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
set "[[=>"#" 2>&1&set/p "&set "]]==<# & del /q # >nul 2>&1"
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

chcp %[[%code-page%]]%
echo ~~%code-page%~~

whoami %[[%its-me%]]%
echo ##%its-me%##
```

For /f with another macro:

```
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
;;set "{{=for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%# in ('" &::
;;set "--=') do @set ""                        &::
;;set "}}==%%#""                               &::
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

:: --examples

::assigning ver output to %win-ver% variable
%{{% ver %--%win-ver%}}%
echo 3: %win-ver%


::assigning hostname output to %my-host% variable
%{{% hostname %--%my-host%}}%
echo 4: %my-host%
```

Answer (score 2):

```
cd %windir%\system32\inetsrv

@echo off

for /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%x in (      
        `appcmd list apppool /text:name`
       ) do (
            echo|set /p=  "%%x - " /text:name & appcmd.exe list apppool "%%x" /text:processModel.identityType
       )

echo %date% & echo %time%

pause
```

Comment: I can't see how this solves the question. `appcmd` isn't a standard program and I can't see where you assign program output to a variable. At last you need some more explanations

Answer (score 2):

I most cases, creating a temporary file named after your variable name might be acceptable. (as you are probably using meaningful variables name...)

Here, my variable name is SSH_PAGEANT_AUTH_SOCK

```
dir /w "\\.\pipe\\"|find "pageant" > %temp%\SSH_PAGEANT_AUTH_SOCK && set /P SSH_PAGEANT_AUTH_SOCK=<%temp%\SSH_PAGEANT_AUTH_SOCK
```