# How to get Python location using Windows batch file?

Tags: python, batch-file, path, pythonpath

I need to create a windows batch script which creates and moves one specific file to `PYTHONPATH\Lib\distutils` folder.

Here is what I am attempting to do:

```
ECHO [build] >> distutils.cfg
ECHO compiler=mingw32 >> distutils.cfg
MOVE distutils.cfg PYTHONPATH\Lib\distutils
```

However, `PYTHONPATH` does not exist but I know that Python location is set in `PATH` which I can check.
How can I parse `PATH` and extract Python location from it?

Comment: Can you try `%PYTHONPATH%`?

Comment: No, `PYTHONPATH` does not exist. To be honest, I don't know a Python installer that creates it. Windows based Python installers all add Python location to `PATH`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since python is in your `PATH` you can use function `where`, which is a Windows analogue of Linux `whereis` function:

```
> where python.exe
```

See details [here](https://superuser.com/questions/21067/windows-equivalent-of-whereis). You can set output of `where` command to a variable and then use it (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359820/batch-files-how-to-set-commands-output-as-a-variable)).

Answer (score 8):

If you have only one `python` instance, you can try this:

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /f %%p in ('where python') do SET PYTHONPATH=%%p
ECHO %PYTHONPATH%
```

Answer (score 0):

Why search for python.exe using WHERE when you know the answer? It's in the path env var! So all you need to do is scan the %path% var. It can be done like this:

```
echo %path% | split ; | find /i "python"
```

OK, here you need the split prog, but it's easily made (in C or batch) and you need it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me by adding `"delims="` value to the `/f` option under the `for` command:

```
@ECHO OFF
for /f "delims=" %%p in ('where python') do SET PYTHONPATH=%%p
ECHO %PYTHONPATH%
```

The result:

> C:\TEMP>pypathtest.bat
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\python.exe