# Batch Script, Time variable

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt

I have a problem with the code I have written and been trying to run in batch. Here it is:

```
echo off

SETLOCAL

set a==%time /t%
if (a!=18:00) goto stop
else goto start

:start
net stop "spooler"
timeout 3 > null
echo "it is done"
timeout 5 > null
echo "now we restarting the service"
timeout 3 > null
net start "spooler"

:stop
PAUSE
ENDLOCAL
```

What it was supposed to do is to check the current time on machine verify with the one pre-conditioned in the code and if it does not match or does, act accordingly. I don't know why (probably because of me being the novice) it returns the error message which says:

> =18:00 was unexpected at this time

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance,

R. Shahin

Answer (score 0):

To assign result of command to variable you need to use [for /f](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359820/how-to-set-commands-output-as-a-variable-in-a-batch-file)
If command does not support c-like syntax.Besides you have built-in `%time%` variable. you need to use something like `if %my_time% neq 18:00`  . Mind that %time% (and time command) are dependent on the time settings. Try something like this:

```
@echo off
pushd "%temp%"
makecab /D RptFileName=~.rpt /D InfFileName=~.inf /f nul >nul
for /f "tokens=3-7" %%a in ('find /i "makecab"^<~.rpt') do (
   set "current-time=%%d"

)
del ~.*
popd

set hours=%current-time:~0,2%
set minutes=%current-time:~3,2%

echo %hours%%minutes%

if "%hours%%minutes%" neq "1800" (
  goto stop
) else (
  goto start
)
....
```

Comment: Thank you. I have added your code and run it and it returned with the error message saying: " | was unexpected at this time "

Comment: @echo off
pushd "%temp%"
makecab /D RptFileName=~.rpt /D InfFileName=~.inf /f nul >nul
for /f "tokens=3-7" %%a in ('find /i "makecab"^<~.rpt') do (
   set "current-time=%%d"

)
del ~.*
popd

set hours=%current-time:~0,2%
set minutes=%current-time:~3,2%

echo %hours%%minutes%

if "%hours%%minutes%" neq "1125" (
  goto stop
) else (
  goto start
)

:start
net stop "spooler"
timeout 3 > null
echo "it is done"
timeout 5 > null
echo "now we restarting the service"
timeout 3 > null
net start "spooler"

:stop
PAUSE
ENDLOCAL