# i want to use command output values to set local admin password via batch file

Tags: batch-file, window

I want to use (`wmic bios get serialnumber`) values to set local admin password in Windows 7.
I wrote a small script which has some bugs. Please help to fix it.

```
@ECHO OFF
set a=wmic bios get serialnumber
net user administrator 123-%a%
pause
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the usual way to get a commands output is a `for /f` loop:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic bios get serialnumber /value ^|find "="') do set %%a
echo %serialnumber%
```

The `find` is used to a) get the correct line and b) convert `wmic`s output from Unicode to ANSI.

Comment: Funny note: on my private system, `wmic bios get serialnumber` gives me `to be filled by OEM`

Comment: you don't need the `find` - for /f omits the empty lines.

Comment: how to use only last charecters in further use? @ stephan

Comment: for example the last four: `set serialnumber=%serialnumber:~-4%`. See `set /?` for details.

Comment: It's not `LF` but `CR` that let's lines to appear non-empty; the most robust way to get rid of them is to nest another `for /F` loop, like this: `for /F "skip=1 delims=" %%a in ('wmic BIOS get SerialNumber') do for /F "delims=" %%b in ("%%a") do set %%b`

Answer (score 0):

This can be considered as duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359820/how-to-set-commands-output-as-a-variable-in-a-batch-file). But wmic commands could need additional [for loop for better parsing](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=4266):

```
 @ECHO OFF

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('wmic bios get serialnumber /format:value') do (

    for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%# in ("%%a") do set "%%#"
)
net user administrator 123-%SerialNumber%
pause
```

Comment: i apply this command in batch file but it does not change  password .my pc serial number is SGH552P6JK.