# How to store python version in a variable inside .bat file in an easy way?

Tags: windows, batch-file

Fairly new to .bat programming I wanted to make a script that does some things according to the installed python version. 
However, I came across my first problem, when it comes to storing the python version, my script looks like the following until now:

```
set version="python --version"
echo %version%
```

Just gives back:

```
"python --version"
```

So the question cuts down to: How to save a a result from a comamnd line command into a variable in bat.file?

I only found this solution:

```
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`python --version`) DO (
SET var=%%F
)
ECHO %var%
```

By this question: [How to set commands output as a variable in a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359820/how-to-set-commands-output-as-a-variable-in-a-batch-file) - which seems too much, if I compare it a bash file - so is there a more elegant way to store the results?

Comment: If you want elegance, use a real scripting language, e.g., cscript or Powershell.  Batch language dates from DOS, was intended only for trivial tasks, and was designed for non-programmers.

Comment: There is no other way as shown in the linked thread: either a `for /F` loop, or redirection to and from a temporary file. Note that the `for /F` approach assigns the last line of the output to the variable, while the other one assigns the first line.