# CMD/Batch get active interface name as variable

Tags: batch-file, variables, cmd, connection

I'm currently having a hard time figuring out how to get the active interface names as a variable output which can be later on used in the code.
I've been reading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359820/how-to-set-commands-output-as-a-variable-in-a-batch-file) a bit, how to use the cmd output as a variable, but I need the specific names which are active.

My current code:

```
    @echo off

    netsh interface show interface


    FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`netsh interface show interface`) DO (
    SET var=%%F
    )
    ECHO %var%
    Pause
```

Which displays this image:
[image]
We can see that due to

> netsh interface show interface

, two connected interfaces and two non connected are shown. However, how do i get f.ex.
Ethernet 2 and WiFi as a variable only like %%V ?

Comment: `FOR /F "skip=2 tokens=3,*"  %%A IN ('netsh interface show interface') DO echo %%B`

Comment: Read the documentation for the `for` command - `for /?|more` from the prompt, or look through SO for thousands of examples of how to use `for`.

Comment: @Stephan, this very useful, but shows now all 4 of them, where I only need the active ones.

Comment: So `Ethernet 2` is connected? At the screenshot it looks very much like `Disconnected`... Please be precise if you want precise answers.

Comment: @Stephan, no. What I need as a result from this example is to get WiFi and Virtual Box as variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get the names of all interfaces that are connected:

```
FOR /F "tokens=3,*" %%A IN ('netsh interface show interface^|find "Connected"') DO echo %%B
```

Note: this is language dependent.

For a language independent solution use `wmic` (which has it's own traps and oddities):

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic nic where (NetConnectionStatus^=2^) get name /value') do (
  for /f "delims=" %%b in ("%%a") do echo %%b
)
```

The inner `for` is to handle the ugly `wmic` line endings

Comment: Thanks, and also for the heads up of language dependency

Answer (score 0):

Because the output of WMIC has the 'ugly' `<CR><CR><LF>` line endings and the value of `NetConnectionID` will often have unwanted trailing spaces, I'd suggest something more like this to retrieve only connected network adapters as variables:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "i=0"
For /F "Skip=1Delims=" %%A In (
 'WMIC NIC Where "NetConnectionStatus=2" Get NetConnectionID'
) Do For /F "Delims=" %%B In ("%%A") Do Call :Sub %%B
Set NIC[
Timeout -1
Exit/B
    :Sub
    Set/A i+=1
    Set "NIC[%i%]=%*"
```

Comment: This gives me an "Environment variable VAR[ not defined" output...?

Comment: Typo. Replace `VAR[` with `NIC[`

Comment: @Tanckom; please consider revising your acceptance of the current answer, for that which I've provided above; Thank you.