# Batch file using powershell

Tags: windows, batch-file

I try to do a batch file to use `subst` function.

Right now, I'm using `paste` in the modify menu of `cmd.exe` to add the string that I want to use.

I found that command :

```
powershell -sta "add-type -as System.Windows.Forms; [windows.forms.clipboard]::GetText()"
```

That shows my string ex.:

```
c:\user\ca\desktop\abb\cde
```

Now what I want to do is to use the `subst` function to get a new letter for that directory, lets say `z:`

so I was doing

```
subst z: c:\user\ca\desktop\abb\cde
```

How can I use the result of `powershell` to be in a variable that I can use with `subst`?

Ex :

```
Subst z: %PowershellResult%
```

What I want to do exactly is a batch file which creates a virtual drive but that I'm able to copy the path in the explorer and it will create the virtual drive without need to type the path in `cmd.exe` or click on the corner of the window, modify and paste.

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/a/6362922/4291215

Comment: Do you need to run it from the cmd prompt or can you run it from the powershell prompt?

Comment: I don't know the difference. What the best ? I can show you my script. The best will be to have a little exe file (that the antivirus don't see like one) that I can run directly in Windows but I'm not a Windows programmer.