# How to pull via adb the latest screenshot from an Android device?

Tags: android, sorting, adb, screenshot

Is there a method to pull via ADB the latest screenshot from my device ?

```
-rw-rw---- 1 root sdcard_rw  137047 2017-11-04 14:02 Screenshot_20171104-140236.png
-rw-rw---- 1 root sdcard_rw   67459 2017-11-04 14:05 Screenshot_20171104-140533.png
-rw-rw---- 1 root sdcard_rw   33939 2017-11-04 14:05 Screenshot_20171104-140557.png
-rw-rw---- 1 root sdcard_rw  329546 2017-11-06 11:12 Screenshot_20171106-111218.png
-rw-rw---- 1 root sdcard_rw  437013 2017-11-13 17:57 Screenshot_20171113-175727.png
-rw-rw---- 1 root sdcard_rw 1200088 2017-11-19 13:44 Screenshot_20171119-134405.png
-rw-rw---- 1 root sdcard_rw  146758 2017-12-12 20:19 Screenshot_20171212-201936.png
-rw-rw---- 1 root sdcard_rw  128158 2017-12-18 11:11 Screenshot_20171218-111151.png
```

How to pull the latest screenshot ?

```
-rw-rw---- 1 root sdcard_rw  128158 2017-12-18 11:11 Screenshot_20171218-111151.png
```

Currently i'm pulling all the files using :

```
adb pull /mnt/sdcard/Screenshots c:\screenshots
```

Then organize them by date in Windows Explorer

**Edit1** I can get the latest file using :

```
adb shell stat -c %y /mnt/sdcard/Screenshots
```

Answer (score 0):

ADB doesn't support flags, so you'll have to pull all the files(names), then do some logic to find the most recent file, then pull that.

It's possible using a script, more info in [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/40459/how-to-pull-only-newer-files-with-adb-pull-android-sdk-utility) related question.

Comment: I can get the last file using **adb shell stat -c %y /mnt/sdcard/Screenshots**

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest capturing the output of the `adb` command that gets ya the latest file and redirecting that to an `adb` command that does the *`pull`ing*.

Based off a somewhat related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6362922/2632107) for saving the output of a command to a variable...

```
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`command`) DO (
    SET var=%%F
)
```

... replace `command` with the command's output to be captured, then...

```
adb pull %var% c:\screenshots
```

... or...

```
adb pull /mnt/sdcard/Screenshots/%var% c:\screenshots
```

... *should* do kinda what ya want.