# How to return string variable from vbs file to batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, vbscript, echo

I have a batch file that runs and calls .vbs file called "SelectNBType.vbs"
The mentioned .vbs file prompt a small UI output for the user to input a string as shown.

```
///Start of Batch file///
For /F "Tokens=2 Delims=" %%I In ('cscript //nologo SelectNBType.vbs') Do 
Set _NBType=%%I

IF %_NBType%==n (
Echo Normal

)
IF %_NBType%=="c" (
Echo Common
)
```

And the .VBS as below

```
////Start of .VBS file
titletext = "Select Notebook Type"  
prompttext = "Enter NB Type"

NBType = inputbox(prompttext & chr(13) & "   (Type n if NORMAL user NB)" & 
chr(13) & "   (Type n if COMMON/POOL user NB)", titletext)

if NBType = "n" Then
x=MsgBox ("You have selected a Normal Notebook",0+32,"Notification")
WScript.Quit 1

elseif NBType = "c" Then
x=MsgBox ("You have selected a Common/Pool Notebook",0+32,"Notification")

End If
```

I am trying to figure out a way to allow the .vbs file to return the output entered by the user as a string to the batch file so that it can be used later in 
the batch file in the if conditions as shown.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set commands output as a variable in a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359820/how-to-set-commands-output-as-a-variable-in-a-batch-file)

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to pass the selection as a string? If you have only two options, you can return each of them with either **WScript.Quit 1** or **WScript.Quit 2** and use that value in the batch file like that:

VBS:

```
titletext = "Select Notebook Type"  
prompttext = "Enter NB Type"

NBType = inputbox(prompttext & chr(13) & "   (Type n if NORMAL user NB)" & chr(13) & "   (Type c if COMMON/POOL user NB)", titletext)

If NBType = "n" Then
   MsgBox "You have selected a Normal Notebook",0+32,"Notification"
   WScript.Quit 1
Elseif NBType = "c" Then
   MsgBox "You have selected a Common/Pool Notebook",0+32,"Notification"
   WScript.Quit 2
End If
```

BAT:

```
cscript //nologo SelectNBType.vbs
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 ECHO You have selected a Normal Notebook.
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 2 ECHO You have selected a Common/Pool Notebook.
```

Comment: Yes, I tested it.

Comment: Thanks, It worked, your solution does what I need.
But just back to the question, is there a way to pass the string back from VBS to batch ?

Comment: see the other answer, the solution is there. at least pay attention to what others offer to you!

Comment: @elzzilogico, the answer you refering to came after I have asked the question, you need a chill pill !

Answer (score 0):

Use `wscript.echo` in VBScript which write to StdOut when run with `CScript` (and a `msgbox` when run with `wscript`).

```
 For /f "delims=" %%A in (`cscript //nologo c:\file.vbs`) do echo %%A
```

See `for /?`.

Comment: not sure, I'm using a phone, but your *for* command quoting may need *usebackq* before *delims*

Comment: *wscript.echo* must be the last line, for *for* to grab the desired output. a script example would have been fine!