# Save Azure CLI command Output using inline script in DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-cli2

**I've been trying to store the output of multiple az cli commands in a variable defined in my pipeline with 0 success.**

This being my last attempt:
[image]

The way I try to make sure is getting pass to the var is by doing an echo, which it outputs this(in all attempts):
[image]

At the end what im trying to achieve is to get the key value stored to use later:
[image]

**Any suggestions on how to do this in the Azure CLI task from Azure DevOps Pipeline?**

PS: Have being trying some commands from shell and batch and must of the attempts failures are related to not recognizing commands(batch/shell) inside the script. Which is confusing since in Azure cli task Docs:

[image]

**Answer**

@4c74356b41 Answer helped a lot since I didn't know I could do query in azure cli commands to get a specific value of a command. But it didn't quite answer my questions. All that said, this link [Set Output Variable in Azure CLI task on VSTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49282998/set-output-variable-in-azure-cli-task-on-vsts?rq=1) has the Answer to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use query path filtering, something like this:

```
--query 'properties.properties.sites[0].key' -o tsv
```

this should output only the key you are interested it. reading:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/query-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest

Comment: This was of much help, thanks. Help me narrow down to just that variable and not loop trough a json obj. Still I need to store it in a variable inside the azure cli task from azure DevOps any ideas on how to do this? I declared the variable but not able to assign it with "=". $var="$(az cli --query 'temp.temp.sites[0]....)

Comment: you can use save the output to variable feature, but I, sadly, never really used that, so I dont know how it works exactly, its the last option of the task step