# Store result of Azure CLI task into release variable

Tags: azure-devops

I have a release pipeline with multiple jobs.

On the first agent job there is an Azure CLI task that retrieves the keys of a storage account on azure.

The command it executes is :

```
az storage account keys list --account-name "$(diagnosticsStorageAccountName)" --resource-group "$(resourceGroup)"
```

What I want to do is store the result of this command and utilize it in a task that is running under a deployment group job.

I've already looked into these resource :

[Set Output Variable in Azure CLI task on VSTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49282998/set-output-variable-in-azure-cli-task-on-vsts)

[How to modify Azure DevOps release definition variable from a release task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53042605/how-to-modify-azure-devops-release-definition-variable-from-a-release-task/53060141#53060141)

I've tried the first one but I didn't get it working.
I didn't bothered with the second because it seems way to hacky.

Is there any way do achieve this that isn't hacky ?

Comment: Why the first one not work for you? Have you get any error? If yes, please share the error info here.

Answer (score 0):

The output values didn't get stored properly.

The output of `az storage account keys list --account-name "$(diagnosticsStorageAccountName)" --resource-group "$(resourceGroup)"`is spread over multiple lines when you use the following syntax:

```
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=testvar;]%myvar%"
```

So one of the problems was that only the first line of the JSON array was being stored into the variable.

I solved this problem in the following way:

```
keys=`az storage account keys list --account-name "$(diagnosticsStorageAccountName)" --resource-group "$(resourceGroup)"`
taskvariable="##vso[task.setvariable variable=_[tempVariable];]"   
echo $taskvariable$keys
```

According to documentation `echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=testvar output=true;]%myvar%` should make the variable available for the whole release. Unfortunately I had no luck with this.

I overcame this using a Powershell task under the same Agent Job (Ubuntu 16.0) :

```
$url = "$($env:SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONSERVERURI)$env:SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECTID/_apis/Release/definitions/$($env:RELEASE_DEFINITIONID)?api-version=5.1"
Write-Host "URL: $url"
$pipeline = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{
    Authorization = "Bearer $(System.AccessToken)"
}

#Parsing JSON string from previous task
$keys = $(@"
$(_tempVariable)
"@ | ConvertFrom-Json)

# Assignment of variable value
$pipeline.variables.[variableName].value = $keys[0].value

####****************** update the modified object **************************
$json = @($pipeline) | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 99


$updatedef = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Put -Body $json -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $(System.AccessToken)"}

write-host "==========================================================" 
Write-host "The value of Variable '[variableName]' is updated to" $updatedef.variables.[variableName].value
write-host "=========================================================="
```

Please note that in order to get this working there are a couple of things you need to do.

First you need to [allow access to the OAuth token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfMlI.png) on the Agent Job.

On top of that you need to give the "Project Collection Build Service".

[Click on security on the release](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGOHF.png) and click on the "Project Collection Build Service" user.

[Change the values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LivaC.png) for the "Edit release" and "Manage release" to allow and save the changes.