# Unable to run nested az cli commands in Azure DevOps pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-cli

I am trying to run an Azure DevOps Task with nested az cli command. I have defined the variables at the beginning of the azure-pipelines.yaml

```
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

variables:
  resourceGroup: test1234
  acrName: taerarawrr2.azurecr.io
```

Within tasks I can access the values by using $(resourceGroup) and $(acrName). Now I want to run an az cli task which uses these two variables, and saves the output of the command in a new variable (ACR_LOGIN_SERVER), which can be later used in the task.

```
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: Run docker image
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: serviceprincipaltest
    scriptType: bash
    scriptLocation: inlineScript
    inlineScript: |
      $ACR_LOGIN_SERVER= $(az acr show --name $(acrName) --resource-group $(resourceGroup) --query "loginServer" --output tsv)
      echo $(ACR_LOGIN_SERVER)
```

This however fails for some reason. I guess there is something wrong with the syntax of this nested command. I've tried using parentheses, $ and quotation marks in various locations but nothing seems to work. I also didn't manage to find any example how such an inline script should be formatted correctly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are the following replies helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems with your script

- The [command substituion](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution) using `$(command)` does not work in Azure DevOps as it tries to replace that with a variable. use the backtick notation Instead: `` `command` ``
- When assigning a variable in bash, you should not prefix the name with `$`, that is for referencing.

```sh
ACR_LOGIN_SERVER=`az acr show --name $(acrName) --resource-group $(resourceGroup) --query "loginServer" --output tsv`

echo $ACR_LOGIN_SERVER
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the link of [Azure CLI task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-cli?view=azure-devops).

You have `$()` around `az acr command`, which will try to find a variable named like that, which is not there. Pls remove that and use the script like below:

```
call {your command}>tmpFile1
set /p myvar= < tmpFile1 
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=testvar;]%myvar%"
```

**OR**

```
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`{your command}`) DO (
SET var=%%F
)
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=testvar;]%var%"
```

Check out this thread: [Set Output Variable in Azure CLI task on VSTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49282998/set-output-variable-in-azure-cli-task-on-vsts)