# git commit hash in dockerfile as label

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

How to add git commit hash or any other dynamically inferred value in Dockerfile.

```
LABEL vcs-ref=$(git rev-parse --short HEAD)
```

Something like this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I found it atlast,

use `docker build --build-arg vcs-ref=$(git rev-parse --short HEAD)`

while building.

But have to initialize the variable in vcs-ref in Dockerfile

```
ARG vcs-ref=0
ENV vcs-ref=$vcs-ref
```

Comment: If you're using Windows, it might be easiest to do this from a bash terminal (as opposed to Windows cmd)

Comment: Finally, what is the complete answer here? ARG, ENV, --buiid-arg all required? A sample snippet with required build-arg would help

Comment: @dexter2305 , all is required. `--build-arg` passes the git hash value into `ARG`, docker passes it from build time `ARG` to runtime `ENV`, your application reads `ENV`. Btw, ARG and ENV should be in one `FROM` block to see each other.

Answer (score 0):

For poor suckers like myself who have to make this happen in Windows CMD, and especially for those who are doing so via NPM, here's a viable approach:

```
git rev-parse --short HEAD > tmpCommitFile && set /p GIT_COMMIT= < tmpCommitFile && del tmpCommitFile && docker build --build-arg vcs-ref=%GIT_COMMIT%
```

This combines the usage of `git rev-parse HEAD`, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6359924/2738164) for some ideas about how to read command output in CMD into a variable, and finally how to pass it as an arg as noted on the other answer here.  CMD makes this much more challenging than expected.

You can feed the `%GIT_COMMIT%` as an argument into whatever you have for a build script instead if there's a layer of abstraction before Docker.