# Trouble setting Batch variable to output of command

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

I have the following line in a `.BAT` file attempt to get a UTC string.

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %g IN ('powershell -command "Get-Date -date (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()-uformat %Y-%m-%dT%H_%M_%SZ"') do (SET VAR=%g)
```

Which makes use of this PowerShell line which works from command prompt.

```
powershell -command "Get-Date -date (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()-uformat %Y-%m-%dT%H_%M_%SZ"
```

And I get the error.

```
Y-dTM_g) was unexpected at this time.
```

This is part of a wider batch file so I can't just do it directly in a PowerShell script.

I took my initial inspiration from here.

[How to set commands output as a variable in a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359820/how-to-set-commands-output-as-a-variable-in-a-batch-file)

**Update:**

Tried this code to no avail.

**test.bat**

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%g IN ('powershell -command "Get-Date -date (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()-uformat %Y-%m-%dT%H_%M_%SZ"') do (
    SET "VAR=%%g"
)

echo %VAR%
```

Getting the output.

```
D:\foo>FOR /F "tokens=*" %g IN ('powershell -command "Get-Date -date (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()-uformat m-H_SZ"') do (SET "VAR=%g" )

D:\foo>(SET "VAR=m-H_SZ" )

D:\foo>echo m-H_SZ
m-H_SZ

D:\foo>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using code inside of a batch consumes the first `%` so you need to double up on it. Simply try this:

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%g IN ('powershell -command "Get-Date -date (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()-uformat %%Y-%%m-%%dT%%H_%%M_%%SZ"') do SET "VAR=%%g"
```

It is also good to always enclose your set variables in double quotes to eliminate any possible whitespace.

The original code will only work when running it from `cmd` terminal.

If you set variables inside a loop you however need `delayedexpansion`:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%g IN ('powershell -command "Get-Date -date (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()-uformat %%Y-%%m-%%dT%%H_%%M_%%SZ"') do (
    SET "VAR=%%g"
)
echo !VAR!
```

for more on delayed expansion, see from `cmd.exe`:

```
set /?
setlocal /?
```