# Troubleshooting a batch file to change time zone

Tags: batch-file, cmd

So I'm trying to build a batch file that will either automatically toggle between 2 time zones; or take a user input and change the time zone accordingly

I tried to have a toggle system but I can't figure out how to store the current time zone based on `tzutil /g` or setup if statements correctly to identify which time zone to change to. I run it in admin mode so thats not the issue.

```
@echo off
echo The current time is:
tzutil /g
echo.
SET /p NewTimeZone="Enter the time zone you wish to change to: "
tzutil /s %NewTimeZone%
```

the first part works fine, it tell the user what time zone it's in and then asks to change it. however that last line is whats causing all the trouble, I can't seem to get it work, for example when I run the code, I type in: `"Mountain Standard Time"` which is the string its needs to change the time however it never goes through, it just closes the program and the time zone never changes

Comment: Have you tried putting quotes around the variable: `tzutil /s "%NewTimeZone%"`

Comment: TBF, it's not uncommon for people not to expect, `Set /P Var="Prompt"` to actually replace, `Prompt` with `Input`. The recommended syntax is `Set /P "Var=Prompt"`, which may help you better see it better.

Comment: [How to store command output.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359820/how-to-set-commands-output-as-a-variable-in-a-batch-file)

Comment: for the "troubleshooting" part: don't run per double click, open a `cmd` window and execute the script from there. It can also be very useful to run it with `echo off`

Answer (score 1):

Usually you get a command's output with a `for /f` loop:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('tzutil /g') do set "org=%%a"
echo original=%org%
```

You can also put it into a file (so it survives even a reboot):

```
>original.zone tzutil /g
type original.zone
```

and get it back with:

```
<original.zone set /p "org="
echo original=%org%
```

and set it back (with both methods):

```
tzutil /s "%org%"
```

You can verify the user's input like:

```
set /p "new=Enter new time zone: "
tzutil /l | findstr /ix "%new%"
if errorlevel 1 ( echo non-existing zone & goto :eof )
tzutil /s "%new%"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use:

```
tzutil /s "%NewTimeZone%"
```

In last line