# Python executing cmd and storing whatever it returns

Tags: python, cmd, subprocess

I am writing a script which is executing CMD commands on Windows. I use it to parse commands to diferent application. Those commands return some values or errors. How do I force Python/CMD to store whatever command returns (no matter if it's returned value or error) in a variable and force it NOT to print it to console. I tried subprocess and os.system() and all of those I tried allows to store value but when command returns an error, it still is being printed to the console and not stored in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

That is a property of the shell / of cmd and how you call the process. By default there's one input stream (stdin) and two output streams (stdout and stderr) - the latter being the default stream for all errors.

You can direct either or both to one another or to stdin or a file by calling the script appropriately. See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/110930/redirecting-error-messages-from-command-prompt-stderr-stdout

For example

myscript 1> output.msg 2>&1

will direct everything into output.msg, including errors. Now combine that output redirection with writing to a variable; that is explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359820/how-to-set-commands-output-as-a-variable-in-a-batch-file).

Answer (score 0):

When executing a command in a shell there is 2 different outputs handlers, *stdout* and *stderr*. Usually *stdout* is used to print normal output and *stderr* to print errors and warnings.

You can use [subprocess.Popen.communicate()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) to read both *stderr* and *stdout*.

```python
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(
    "dir", 
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
    shell=True
)
(stdout, stderr) = p.communicate()

print(stdout.decode('utf-8'))  # Standard output
print(stderr.decode('utf-8'))  # Standard error
```

Comment: This solution works but when I used os.system() Python used to execute the command and go on with next lines. But with subprocess.Popen() Python waits with another line, until the application (that I started via CMD) is closed. How to force it to "go on"?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with "waits with another line". Does the command expect an input? If so, you can do `p.communicate(input="whatever you want to send")` to send data to the command standard input.

Comment: from the code you wrote, Python executes: 
'import subprocess
cmd = subprocess.Popen("udt.exe", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE) #the app it runs is a window application'
and then pauses. nothing happens. if I manually close the udt.exe application, Python code resumes and executes whatever is next