# How can I run Python from a .cmd file, and have it pass a string back to the batch file, then SET a variable to this string?

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, cmd

I intend to run a .cmd file, which will have

`python my_program.py "Short string of information to pass to Python"`

in it. The Python program will determine the path that the .cmd file needs, so I want to pass it as a string back to the .cmd when it finishes running, and then I want the .cmd to assign it to a variable, like so:

`SET MY_VARIABLE <string-from-Python-here>`

Is there a way I can do this? This Python file may also need to do some configuration first. We are running Python 2.7.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6359820/214671

Answer (score 0):

you can save Text File as batch file .bat
python.exe "path\my_program.py"
after that you can use windows schedule to schedule your script.
for configuration you can save it in one file and read it from python itself.