# How to write call command in batch file conditionally?

Tags: batch-file

I have two lines of call command in batch file like this:

```
call execute.cmd
call launch.cmd
```

My need is to call the launch.cmd if and only if call to execute.cmd succeeds.
So is there any way by which can I put some condition here?

execute.cmd does not return any value here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `execute.cmd` returns an integer than you can use a [`IF command`](http://www.computerhope.com/if.htm) to check it's return value and if it matches the desired one than you can call `launch.cmd`

Suppose that `execute.cmd` returns 0 if it is successful or an integer >= 1 otherwise. The batch would look like this:

```
rem call the execute command
call execute.cmd
rem check the return value (referred here as errorlevel)
if %ERRORLEVEL% ==1 GOTO noexecute
rem call the launch command
call launch.cmd

:noexecute
rem since we got here, launch is no longer going to be executed
```

note that the `rem` command is used for comments.

HTH,
JP

Comment: exceute.cmd returns 0 if it is successful and 1 if not, so problem got solved using your logic, thanks a lot. As u replied first, I'm accepting your answer, even though the answer by @jhclark looks correct.

Comment: @Anand K Gupta your wellcome :)

Comment: You may also achieve the same thing with Windows Batch && combination this way: call execute.cmd && call launch.cmd

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is a duplicate of [How do I make a batch file terminate upon encountering an error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/734598/how-do-i-make-a-batch-file-terminate-upon-encountering-an-error).

Your solution here would be:

```
call execute.cmd
if %errorlevel% neq 0 exit /b %errorlevel%
call launch.cmd
if %errorlevel% neq 0 exit /b %errorlevel%
```

Unfortunately, it looks like Windows batch files have no equivalent of UNIX bash's `set -e` and `set -o pipefail`. If you're willing to abandon the very limited batch file language, you could try Windows PowerShell.