# Stop batch script from executing while encountering error

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing, dos

So I'm building multiple client using the same batch script. If there's an error while building one, that process simply stops and continues with the next one. Because there's a lot of output on the screen and I'm doing other things, most of the time I miss that there was a build error.

Is there a way to stop executing the following tasks if there's an error, and show a popup message to get my attention? Or at least stop executing so when I come back to the command window I can see that there was a failure?

```
@echo off

if "%1"=="?" GOTO HELP

if NOT "%1"=="" set rev=%1
if NOT "%2"=="" set version=%2

@echo on
rem build one 
call perl buildClient.pl -brandName="myBrand" -group="group1" 

rem build two 
call perl buildClient.pl -brandName="myBrand" -group="group2" 

rem build three
call perl buildClient.pl -brandName="myBrand" -group="group3" 

rem build four 
call perl buildClient.pl -brandName="myBrand" -group="group4" 


    @echo off

    goto EXIT

    :HELP
    cls
    echo.
    echo.
    echo usage: buildbrand.bat [revision] [version] [group]
    echo.
    echo        ?           = this help screen
    echo.
    echo        revision    = build version
    echo                      Example: 5.2.31
    echo        group       = group of phones or phone name
    echo                      Example: SonyEricsson\K750
    echo.
    :EXIT
    set version=
    set rev=
    set brandName=
    PAUSE
```

Comment: let's say building group1 failed. I want to stop there and get myself notified rather than continuing to processing group2.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think that something like `call command arguments||echo The command failed && pause` should work.

Comment: @ProfPickle That is assuming perl gives an error level which I would assume it doesn't.  Tony what output does it give if it fails?

Comment: Assuming `perl` is another batch file, you can add `EXIT %errorlevel%` to exit the `perl` batch file and set `%ERRORLEVEL%` to the value that the perl compiler returned.  Then you can check `%errorlevel%` after each `call perl` to see if you need to error out...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make a batch file terminate upon encountering an error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/734598/how-do-i-make-a-batch-file-terminate-upon-encountering-an-error)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Check the errorlevel in an if statement, and then exit /b (exit the batch file only, not the entire cmd.exe process) for values of 1 or greater."

```
if %errorlevel% neq 0 exit /b %errorlevel%
```

Look here for details: [How do I make a batch file terminate upon encountering an error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/734598/how-do-i-make-a-batch-file-terminate-upon-encountering-an-error)

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax for stopping execution if error is:

> if ERRORLEVEL 1 exit

Answer (score -4):

Just a tip try using

```
if %ERRORLEVEL% NOT 1 
exit 0
```

in your code. this should exit on error.