# Does Windows XP really have negative error codes?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I consider myself as a quite proficient in windows batch programming, but I was shocked when read that Windows XP can return negative error code to a batch file.
If that's true, I'll have to fix hundreds of my batch files.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/734744/2536047

1. Is there any proof of that? I've never met one.
2. Is that specific to all newer windowses or Windows XP only? (though if there will be proof, I hope I'll be able to test it on my own)

Comment: Yes, some programs return hugely negative numbers - no examples I'm afraid, but TTBOMK it affects all newer windows too.

Comment: The ability to return negative errorlevels begin when MS-DOS disappear as standalone operating system (MS-DOS version 7) and became in part of Windows 97.

Comment: It's entirely normal.  Programs that terminate due to an exception or a COM error code will return negative values.  Only 0 has a meaning, "no error", anything else is possible and should be interpreted as "it didn't work".

Comment: @HansPassant - Yes, the generally followed convention is zero means success and non-zero means some form of error. But there are some programs that use the return code to indicate some valid expected value rather than an error. For example, negative could represent an error, and greater or equal to zero could represent a count.

Answer (score 5):

You can test it with the following `script.bat`:

```
@ECHO Off &SETLOCAL
EXIT /b -1
```

---

Session log:

```
>type script.bat
@ECHO Off &SETLOCAL
EXIT /b -1
>script

>echo %errorlevel%
-1
```

Answer (score 2):

The exit code of a Windows process is a 32-bit signed integer, although Microsoft frequently doesn't treat them as signed numbers. A host of their error codes are represented in hexadecimal with the MSB turned on. Example: [SMS Error Codes](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb632794.aspx)

@Endoro's example is sufficient proof. Exit codes range from [-2147483648,2147483647].
Here's a script that demonstrates the limits:

```
SETLOCAL
PROMPT $G$G$G$S

:: [-2147483648,2147483647]

CALL :TEST_EXIT -2147483648
ECHO %ERRORLEVEL%

CALL :TEST_EXIT -2147483649
ECHO %ERRORLEVEL%

CALL :TEST_EXIT 2147483647
ECHO %ERRORLEVEL%

CALL :TEST_EXIT 2147483648
ECHO %ERRORLEVEL%


GOTO :EOF

:TEST_EXIT
EXIT /B %1
```

...and the output (note the overflow/underflow):

```
C:\temp\so>SETLOCAL

C:\temp\so>PROMPT $G$G$G$S 

>>> CALL :TEST_EXIT -2147483648 

>>> EXIT /B -2147483648 

>>> ECHO -2147483648 
-2147483648

>>> CALL :TEST_EXIT -2147483649 

>>> EXIT /B -2147483649 

>>> ECHO 2147483647 
2147483647

>>> CALL :TEST_EXIT 2147483647 

>>> EXIT /B 2147483647 

>>> ECHO 2147483647 
2147483647

>>> CALL :TEST_EXIT 2147483648 

>>> EXIT /B 2147483648 

>>> ECHO -2147483648 
-2147483648

>>> GOTO :EOF
```