# windows 7 exit batch file when command fails

Tags: batch-file, windows-7

I'm writing a batch file on windows 7 that executing some commands one after another:

```
copy source1 dest1
call someFile1.bat
copy source2 dest2
call someFile2.bat
copy source3 dest3
```

Is there a way to return error code 1 if any of the commands returns error code 1?

Thanks!

Comment: `exit /b %ERRORLEVEL%` will return from a `call` with the same exit code as the most recent command exited.  Then you can just `call someFile2.bat || exit /b` if `someFile2.bat` exits non-zero.  This will require modifying someFile1.bat and someFile2.bat, adding error handling where needed.

Comment: For future readers, I found my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/734598/how-do-i-make-a-batch-file-terminate-upon-encountering-an-error?noredirect=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a way. The code must check the return code.

```
SET EXITCODE=0

copy source1 dest1
call someFile1.bat
if ERRORLEVEL 1 goto Failed
copy source2 dest2
call someFile2.bat
if ERRORLEVEL 1 goto Failed
copy source3 dest3
goto Success

:Failed
set EXITCODE=1
:Success
EXIT /B %EXITCODE%
```

If you want to check to see that the COPY commands work, that will be another if statement.

Comment: Thanks! I do needed also checking the copy. not the prettiest script i've written, but worked like a charm :)