# HTML Help Workshop returns error after successfully compiled .chm file

Tags: cmd, doxygen, html-help-workshop

I'm facing a quite weird failure after I successfully compiled a .chm file with *HTML Help Workshop*'s `hhc.exe`.

I created a documentation of my source code with *Doxygen*. *Doxygen* creates if you enable `GENERATE_HTMLHELP` in the doxygen file:

> If the GENERATE_HTMLHELP tag is set to YES then doxygen generates three
>   additional HTML index files: index.hhp, index.hhc, and index.hhk. The  index.hhp
>   is a project file that can be read by Microsoft's HTML Help Workshop (see:
>   http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21138) on Windows.

After *Doxygen* creates those files, I want to create the .chm file with *HTML Help Workshop*. For that reason I call `hhc.exe` in a CMD. After that I can open the .chm file and everything seems fine. But if I ask the CMD for the current `errorlevel`, it outputs:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\HTML Help Workshop\hhc.exe" index.hhp
Microsoft HTML Help Compiler 4.74.8702

Compiling C:\... folder path ...\index.chm

Compile time: 0 minutes, 0 seconds
37      Topics
346     Local links
12      Internet links
0       Graphics

Created C:\... folder path ...\index.chm, 88,740 bytes
Compression decreased file by 194,682 bytes.

echo %errorlevel%
1
```

Does anyone have an idea of what the h... is going wrong here and how I can avoid that problem that it's compiled successfully but still returns an error? How can I figure out what's the problem instead of an error "1"?

The problem is that my build server (TFS2015) returns the error and the build is failed.

Comment: This is problem that surfaces regularly and by head it comes from the hhc.exe giving back a non expected return value. Which version of doxygen are you using and are you using hhc.exe from withing doxygen or separately?

Comment: Version of Doxygen: 1.8.11 and I'm running it separately (build script and repeatable in CMD ). Both has the same behavior.

Comment: What happens if you run it inside doxygen? or isn't this possible. In the later case you have ignore error code in the build script file.

Comment: If i run it inside doxyfile, it will be the same behavior. The .chm will be created but my build will fail

Comment: Just to get it straight  about the part "If i run it inside doxyfile, it will be the same behavior" did you try it or is this a guess (formulation looks like the last)?

Comment: Sorry, it will not - it is! So i tried it already and I got the same error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*HTML Help Workshop* is installed with 2 main executables:

1. `hhc.exe` is the **console** version of the HTML Help Compiler.
2. `hhw.exe` is the **Windows** GUI version of HTML Help Compiler.

But the compilation of the HTML Help Project (hhp) to Compiled HTML (chm) is not directly done by those two executables.

Both use for compilation `hha.dll` - the HTML Help Author library - by calling the exported function `HHA_CompileHHP`.

The exported functions of this library are:

- EditHhCtrlObject
- EditHhCtrlScript
- FreeFilterDIB
- HHA_CompileHHP
- LoadFilterImage
- LoadJpeg

Microsoft has not published any documentation nor the function declarations of those functions as far as I know.

I **suppose** from some quick tests with `hhc.exe` that the function `HHA_CompileHHP` has `BOOL` as return type which is `int` and returns on success `TRUE`, i.e. the value `1`, and on failure `FALSE`, i.e. the value `0`. And it looks like `hhc.exe` uses this return value without inverting the value as exit/return code.

Therefore the `errorlevel` is `1` on success and `0` on failure.

The tests I made to verify my assumption:

1. Run HTML Help compiler with name of a project file which does not exist:

   ```
   hhc.exe index_1.hhp
   ```

   > Unable to open index_1.hhp.

   The exit code respectively `errorlevel` is 0. This error message is printed by `hhc.exe` because the error message can be found in `hhc.exe`.
2. Set read-only file attribute on already existing output file `index.chm` and run HTML Help compiler:

   ```
   attrib +r index.chm & hhc.exe index.hhp & attrib -r index.chm
   ```

   > HHC5010: Error: Cannot open "C:... folder path ...\index.chm". Compilation stopped.

   The exit code respectively `errorlevel` is 0. This error message is printed by `hha.dll` because this error message can be found only in `hha.dll`.
3. Rename a *.htm file explicitly specified in `index.hhp` and run HTML Help Compiler:

   ```
   ren "file.htm" "renamed file.htm" & hhc.exe index.hhp & ren "renamed file.htm" "file.htm"
   ```

   > Microsoft HTML Help Compiler 4.74.8702
   >   
   >   Compiling C:... folder path ...\index.chm
   >   
   >   HHC5003: Error: Compilation failed while compiling *file.htm*.
   >   
   >   The following files were not compiled:
   >   *file.htm*

   The exit code respectively `errorlevel` is 0. This error message is printed also by `hha.dll` because this error message can be found also only in `hha.dll`.

All error messages are written to handle **STDOUT** and not to **STDERR** as typical for console applications. There was never another value than 0 or 1 assigned to `errorlevel` which is the reason why I suppose the function `HHA_CompileHHP` returns a simple boolean value.

**Conclusion:**

The opposite as usual must be done to evaluate on success/failure of an HTML Help compilation for example by using in the batch file:

```
"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\HTML Help Workshop\hhc.exe" index.hhp
if not errorlevel 1 exit /B 1
```

In HTML Help Project file (*.hhp file) in section `[OPTIONS]` a log file can be specified with `Error log file=...` into which all messages output by `HHA_CompileHHP` are written **additionally** to printing them to **STDOUT**.

But in this case with *Doxygen* generating the *.hhp file it would be easier to redirect **STDOUT** in the batch file to a log file although this is also not really needed because most likely the Team Foundation Server is capturing the messages already to a log. (I don't have Team Foundation Server installed.)

Comment: Thanks Mofi, thanks for the verification. I added a command that it will success if the errorlevel is 1.

Answer (score -1):

HTML Workshop is a GUI program. When using CMD interactively it does not wait for GUI programs to exit. Therefore there is no error code.

`Echo %errorlevel%` interactively will never show an error code as well.

This two ways will

```
Dir && Echo Success || Echo Failure

Dir df:\ & Echo %errorlevel%
```

[See my answer at [Trouble with renaming folders and sub folders using Batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31820569/trouble-with-renaming-folders-and-sub-folders-using-batch) to see what it means]

You will have to read HTML Workshop's documentation to see if it sets an errorlevel. Most GUI programs don't bother.

Comment: Look at his screen shot before commenting.

Comment: I'm confused ... looks to me like he has errorlevel=1.

Comment: I'm having errorlevel = 1! As you can see in my screenshot