# How to make batch file stop when command fails

Tags: batch-file

How do i make a `batch` file to stop running other/next commands if first or any other command fails.

```
call grails clean 
call grails compile 
call grails package
call grails war
```

If `grails clean` fail then `grails compile` should not run and same with others.

Comment: Is `grails` a batch file or an executable? Please specify in your batch file `grails` with file extension. The command `call` is needed only for batch files, not for console applications. To exit a batch file on previous command exited not successful use `if errorlevel 1 goto :EOF` or `if errorlevel 1 exit /B 1`. Run in a command prompt window `if /?` and `goto /?` for help on those two commands. Run in command prompt window also `exit /?` for help on this command in case of `grails` is a batch file which needs to exit with an exit code greater 0 on error for parent batch file exit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make a batch file terminate upon encountering an error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/734598/how-do-i-make-a-batch-file-terminate-upon-encountering-an-error)

Comment: `grails` is a batch file @Mofi

Comment: If `grails` sets the [`ErrorLevel`](http://ss64.com/nt/errorlevel.html), an `if not ErrorLevel 1` (meaning `ErrorLevel` < `1`) query could be used; if `grails` sets the exit code, use [`&&` operator](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) (execute next command in case of zero exit code); `ErrorLevel` and exit code are equal most of the time but are actually different things...

Answer (score 4):

The `ERRORLEVEL` environment variable holds the return value of the last executed command.
So you can use:

```
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
  echo "Previous command execution failed."
  exit %ERRORLEVEL%
)
```

Please see http://steve-jansen.github.io/guides/windows-batch-scripting/part-3-return-codes.html for details.

Comment: Wouldn't %ERRORLEVEL% inside the if be the result of echo?